# Makefile builds source files from different directories into the same object directory

Tags: c, makefile, gnu-make

I have a c project with directory layout like this

```
src1
    -a.c
    -b.c
src2
    -c.c
    -d.c
objects
```

I'm trying to compile a/b/c/d into objects files and saved them into objects directory and here is part of my Makefile.

```
src1 = src1/
src1 = src2/
obj = objects/
src1_files = a.c b.c
src2_files = c.c d.c
source_files = $(addprefix $(src1), $(src1_files)) $(addprefix $(src1), $(src2_files)) 
objects := $(addprefix $(obj), $(src1_files:.c=.o)) $(addprefix $(obj), $(src2_files:.c=.o))

$(obj)%.o: $(source_files)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

all: $(objects)
```

However when I try to run make, I got the following.

```
gcc -Wall -c src1/a.c -o objects/a.o
gcc -Wall -c src1/a.c -o objects/b.o
gcc -Wall -c src1/a.c -o objects/c.o
gcc -Wall -c src1/a.c -o objects/d.o
```

Anyone knows why is it doing that?

Comment: `$(addprefix $(src1), $(src2_files)` --> `$(addprefix $(src2), $(src2_files)`

Comment: @Gaurav this isn't enough yet

Comment: This is what I came across while reading the `Makefile`. I have to execute the Makefile to catch any other issue.!  :-|

Comment: There is yet another typo: `src1 = src2/` (in 2nd line).

Comment: @Gaurav it's correct of course, but this Makefile has, apart from the typos, a conceptual error, it would never work like this ;)

Comment: @FelixPalmen Yeah, I read your answer!! Nice Explanation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After having read the [answer of Felix Palmen](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48146709/7478597), especially the last sentence

> If you really want the objects directly in your objects directory, you need two pattern rules, one matching the sources in `src1` and one matching the sources in `src2`.

I modified the `Makefile` accordingly (out of curiosity):

```
src1 = src1/
src2 = src2/
obj = objects/
src1_files = a.c b.c
src2_files = c.c d.c
source_files = $(addprefix $(src1), $(src1_files)) $(addprefix $(src2), $(src2_files)) 
objects := $(addprefix $(obj), $(src1_files:.c=.o)) $(addprefix $(obj), $(src2_files:.c=.o))

$(obj)%.o: src1/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

$(obj)%.o: src2/%.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

all: $(objects)
```

I tested in `bash` on cygwin:

```
$ mkdir src1 src2 objects

$ touch src1/a.c src1/b.c src2/c.c src2/d.c

$ make
cc  -c src1/a.c -o objects/a.o
cc  -c src1/b.c -o objects/b.o
cc  -c src2/c.c -o objects/c.o
cc  -c src2/d.c -o objects/d.o

$
```

...and it worked.

(I left out the detail about building the `objects` directory – just created it manually).

Comment: Yep, that's what I just briefly described in my last paragraph. Wouldn't recommend this route, at least if the amount of source directories will increase later, but it works :) (and therefore answers the immediate question)

Comment: This was my intention to demonstrate what you suggested. May be, I should've stated more clearly my answer as add-on to your.

Comment: I understood that, just wanted to confirm this was what I meant! (and add the doubt about it being the "right thing to do", but this of course depends on the situation) ;)

Answer (score 2):

This is not how pattern rules work. When trying to build an object file with your rule, `make` tries to replace a `%` in the prerequisite with whatever matches the `%` in your target -- but your prerequisite doesn't contain a `%`, so it's just taken literally. In your recipe, you just take the first one from the prerequisites list (`$<`), which is always the same.

The easiest thing to do is to just replicate the directory structure below your object directory, this is what most Makefiles will actually do. Something like this:

```
objects := $(addprefix $(obj), $(source_files:.c=.o))

$(obj)%.o: %.c
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

You will need to make sure the directories exist, e.g. like this (untested):

```
objdirs := $(obj)$(src1) $(obj)$(src2)

$(objdirs):
    mkdir -p $@

$(obj)%.o: %.c | $(objdirs)
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@
```

---

If you really want the objects directly in your `objects` directory, you need two pattern rules, one matching the sources in `src1` and one matching the sources in `src2`.